# Jest unit testing aws cdk (v1) NOT SERVERLESS

Tags: amazon-web-services, unit-testing, facebook-graph-api, jestjs, aws-cdk

https://github.com/dabit3/cdk-graphql-backend
using this link I have created the same cdk (version 1) project with redshift database.
How can I test the (Appsync, GraphQl, Lambda) using the Jest. Already checked the Jest testing example only found one example related to sqs queue test. So I need specific answer to this if anyone can help.

IN THE lib file

```
const api = new appsync.GraphqlApi(this, "Api", {
  name: "api-name",
  schema: appsync.Schema.fromAsset("graphql/schema.graphql"),
  authorizationConfig: {
    defaultAuthorization: {
      authorizationType: appsync.AuthorizationType.API_KEY,
      apiKeyConfig: {
        expires: cdk.Expiration.after(cdk.Duration.days(365)),
      },
    },
  },
  xrayEnabled: true,
});

   const wLambda = new lambda.Function(
      this,
      "ApiHandler",
      {
        runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_16_X,
        handler: "index.handler",
        layers: [layers.consolidatedWeatherAPILayer],
        code: lambda.Code.fromAsset("lambdas/functions", { exclude: ["*.ts"] }),
        memorySize: 1024,
        timeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(30),
      }
    );

const lambdaDS = new appsync.LambdaDataSource(this, "LambdaDataSource", {
  api: api,
  lambdaFunction: wLambda,
});
```

code written in the test file:

```
import "@aws-cdk/assert/jest";
import { Stack } from "@aws-cdk/core";
import myStack = require("../lib/test-cdk-project-stack");

test("appsync cloudformation", () => {
  const stack = new Stack()
  new myStack.TestCdkProjectStack(stack, "appsynCloud");
  expect(stack).toHaveResource("AWS::AppSync::GraphQLApi", {
    xrayEnabled: true,
  });
});
```

Result:
[output with toHaveResource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9P52f.png)

If I use "toHaveProperty" instead of "toHaveResource"
Result:
[output with toHaveProperty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwyYd.png)

maybe I'm using the wrong function.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `hasResourceProperties`, I have a couple examples here: [example tests](https://github.com/CodingWithFaruci/cdk-ts-library/blob/main/test/infra/cdk-ts-library.test.ts)